# How refresh server component NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Good afternoon, I would like to ask a question, I am creating a filter with queryparams and using SSR.

The first request is going fine, as expected

However, when I apply the filter it continues with the same products, only if I refresh the page with F5 it applies the filter correctly.

SSR Page:

```js
const ColecaoPage = async ({ params, searchParams }) => {

  let produtos;
  let queryParams;

  const { data } = await api.get('/produto/colecao/' + params.slug)

  if (!searchParams || Object.keys(searchParams).length === 0) {
    const response = await api.get('/produto?Colecao=' + data.Colecao.Colecao_ID)

    produtos = response.data;
  } else {
    queryParams = queryString.stringify(searchParams);
    const response = await api.get(`/produto?Colecao=${data.Colecao.Colecao_ID}&${queryParams}`)
    console.log(`/produto?Colecao=${data.Colecao.Colecao_ID}&${queryParams}`);
    console.log('filtro aplicado');
    produtos = response.data;
  }

  return <ColecaoScreen produtos={produtos} colecao={data} parametros={queryParams} />;
};

export default ColecaoPage;
```

Filter Function:

```js
const AplicarFiltro = async (colecao) => {
    let queryParams = '';

    if (tamanhoSelecionado.length > 0) {
      queryParams += `${queryParams ? '&' : ''}Tamanho=${tamanhoSelecionado.join(',')}`;
    }

    if (corSelecionada.length > 0) {
      queryParams += `${queryParams ? '&' : ''}Cor=${corSelecionada.join(',')}`;
    }

    if (preco[0] > 0 || preco[1] < 500) {
      queryParams += `${queryParams ? '&' : ''}Preco_Min=${preco[0]}&Preco_Max=${preco[1]}`;
    }

    router.push(`/colecao/${colecao.Url}${queryParams ? `?${queryParams}` : ''}`);
  }
```

In short, how do I update server component products?

I did a test here by placing the log console within the function of pulling products from the api and when I apply the filter, console.log appears, the products are coming correctly, but when passing to the component it does not update the products, the old ones remain I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: please show ColecaoScreen